# Twig template JSON to something readable

Tags: laravel, twig, octobercms

I use october CMS and trying to extend some futures on one of the modules.

I have settings column in my DB, that have several fields. But when user type something in this fields goes to DB like JSON : `{"about":"dsadasdas","nickname":"bojko"}`  or `{"nickname":"qnica","about":"test"}`

When i try to dispalay this in profile page `{{ueuser.user.settings}}` first gives me this error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Array to string conversion").

I read a lot and add `{{ueuser.user.settings|join(',')}}`

Now on display shows [image] or [image]

But i want to add some style To show something like
Nickname: qnica
About: test
.... and etc.

How can i do this? Here is a `{{dump(ueuser.user.settings)}}` [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html

```
{# example #}
<ul>
    {% for key, value in ueuser.user.settings %}
        <li>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```